# IOS app update has 2 iOS distributed certificates but their private key are not installed

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store

I want update an app to Apple store. When I was going to validate my archive file to App Store it showed an error.

> has two distributed certificate but their private key are not
>   installed . Contact the creator one of these certificate the copy of
>   the private key

**here is error screen shot**

[image]

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: This means, the certificate is not created fro your mac. As a common fix, find the mac that is created this certificate and export them from that mac. Then install on your mac

Comment: thanks@ Johnykutty I have created the certificate from my mac

Comment: @EnamulHaque: How did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the file missing in your keychain. This is mainly because of the certificates are created on the diffrent system so ask the developer or the whosever project you are running to provide you with p12 certificates along with the password if set 
Then just double click the certificates and enter the password and you will be asked for administrator password enter the credentials and your problem will be solved.Plz let me know if it works for you.

thanks

Comment: Hello @Lucky I have double click .p12 file then it show password then I gave password.then again shows same error

Answer (score 1):

Delete your cetificate and Follow these steps to create new one:

1. Open `Keychain Access` and go to certificate assistant > Request a certificate from a certificate Authority.

[image]

2. Enter developer's email address and check last two options as shown in figure.

[image]

It will generate `certSigningRequest`, we will use it.

3. Go to developers account > Certificate, Identifier & Profiles > Certificates and revoke your current certificate and create new : 
   [image]

and select App Store and Ad Hoc under Production :

[image]

And click continue and upload `certSigningRequest` we created and after that press done, and download that certificate and install on your system, and try to upload again.

Answer (score -1):

i solved it by clicking on manage certificates, then i clicked on arrow sign adjacent to plus sign below and click on apple dsitribution...that automatically downloaded the correct certificate